# force VAT number / only sell to B2B customers

Tags: attributes, checkout, customer, b2b, vat

I have a situation where a shop can only sell to B2B customers. The boss suggests that the simplest way to force this validation is using the VAT ID - if a customer doesn't enter a VAT ID, then the checkout cannot continue.

Does anyone know how to best implement this? I don't find a specific extension for that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the "company" field required as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456794/magento-make-the-field-company-required

Not sure about the exact steps for default vat field number, seems thy are same as for the company field.

If you are looking for the extension, try "customer attributes" module, where you can create any fields, like VAT and make them mandatory from the admin panel, no need to change database or templates.

Comment: OK thanks. What about the VAT ID field - making both a validation check that the number is correct, and making this an essential field. Is that going to be easy to do? I'm happy to buy an extension if needed.

Comment: this also looks to be a part solution: http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/registration-process-how-do-i-make-the-tax-vat-field-required-63-nbsp--82801.html

Comment: just need to add validation to that.